# What does ssh -T git@bitbucket.org do?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a section in a bash script I am writing to provision a vagrant box:

```
ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
git clone git@bitbucket.org:my-username/api.git ~/html
sudo mv ~/html /usr/share/nginx
```

This section clones from a private bitbucket repo. It works fine, but if I remove `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` I get an an authentication error when attempting to clone.

What is the purpose of `ssh -T` and why can't I authenticate without running this command?